# Plotting two graphs, one below the other, in shiny panel

Tags: r, plot, shiny-server, shiny

I am producing two graphs.

Right now they are showing up in two different panels (tabs)

```
ui.r
mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Summary", dataTableOutput("dis")),
        tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot1")),
        tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot2"))
      )
    )

server.r

output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    Plot1
  })


output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    Plot1
 })
```

I am wondering how can i show these graphs one below the other in the same panel, and not two different panels like how it is now. Thanks folks for helping.

Comment: for ggplot2 plots you can do `grid.arrange(gplot, gplot, ncol=1)`. for base plots you can do `par(mfrow=c(2,1)) ; plot(…) ; plot(…); par(mfrow=c(1,1))`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can wrap them in a `fluidRow` or just list them inside the same `tabPanel`

```
shinyApp(
    shinyUI(
        fluidPage(
            mainPanel(
                tabsetPanel(
                    tabPanel("Summary", dataTableOutput("dis")),
                    tabPanel("Plot",
                             # fluidRow(...)
                                 plotOutput("plot1"),
                                 plotOutput("plot2")
                             )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    shinyServer(function(input, output) {
        output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
            plot(1:10, 1:10)
        })

        output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
            plot(1:10 ,10:1)
        })

        output$dis <- renderDataTable({})
    })
)
```

Wrapping them in a `fluidRow` provides easy control over individual plot attributes like widths for example,

```
tabPanel("Plot",
         fluidRow(
             column(8, plotOutput("plot1")),
             column(12, plotOutput("plot2"))
         ))
```

Answer (score 0):

If we do it like this:

```
tabPanel("Plot",
    plotOutput("plot1"),
    plotOutput("plot2")
    )
```

plot1 will show on the top and plot2 will show on the bottom.
But if we do it using fluidRow:

```
tabPanel("Plot",
    fluidRow(
        column(8, plotOutput("plot1")),
        column(12, plotOutput("plot2"))
         ))
```

Then we can show the two plots side by side.